# Batch STDOUT / STDERR redirection weirdness

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm running into a strange issue with batch scripts and redirection to logs while trying to run some scripts during the provisioning phase of a Windows 2012R2 system.

The general flow is something like this:

execute init.cmd:

init.cmd:

```
@echo off
echo init - foo
call start.cmd >start.log 2>&1
echo init - bar
```

start.cmd:

```
@echo off
echo start - foo
call test1.cmd >test1.log 2>&1
echo start - bar
call test2.cmd >test2.log 2>&1
echo start - baz
```

test1.cmd

```
@echo off
echo hello
```

test2.cmd

```
@echo off
echo aloha
```

What happens is that I get a start.log that looks like:

```
start - foo
```

Then I get a test1.log that looks like:

```
hello
start - bar
```

And finally a test2.log that looks like:

```
aloha
start - baz
init - bar
```

Basically, it appears that once I redirect STDOUT/STDERR, it redirects it for *everything*, until I redirect it elsewhere, at which point, everything now goes to the new place.  I've tried several ways of doing the redirection, calling subroutines like call `:test1 >test1.log 2>&1` and directing those, or wrapping in `>start.log 2>&1 (commands)`, all of the do the same thing.

I put these sample scripts on a Windows 10 box though, and it all worked fine.

Is there something I'm missing here?

EDIT:

Here's the real scripts:

init.cmd:

```
@echo off
md %SYSTEMDRIVE%\logs
curl -sf -o %SYSTEMROOT%\temp\win_installer.cmd http://10.6.7.20/cblr/svc/op/script/system/acme.example.com/?script=win_installer.cmd
call %SYSTEMROOT%\temp\win_installer.cmd >%SYSTEMDRIVE%\logs\installer.log 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Installer failed
    goto:eof
)
shutdown /r /t 0
```

win_installer.cmd:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

echo Mounting Samba Share WINLOGS to L:
net use L: \\10.6.7.20\WINLOGS
if exist "L:" (
    md L:\example.acme.com
)

echo Beginning run stage
call :run
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo win2012r2.cmd failed to run completely
    goto :err
)
echo run stage completed successfully

if not exist "L:\example.acme.com" (
    echo Failed to create L:\example.acme.com
    echo This isn't fatal, so going to continue
    echo Logs will still be kept locally
)

echo Copying setupact.log
copy %SYSTEMROOT%\Panther\setupact.log L:\acme.example.com
echo Copying setuperr.log
copy %SYSTEMROOT%\Panther\setuperr.log L:\acme.example.com
echo Copying %SYSTEMDRIVE%\logs\win2012r2.log
copy %SYSTEMDRIVE%\logs\win2012r2.log L:\acme.example.com

echo Beginning netconf stage
call :netconf
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Could not configure network
    goto :err
)
echo netconf stage completed successfully
goto :end

:run
echo Downloading install script for win2012r2.cmd
echo curl -sf -o %SYSTEMROOT%\temp\win2012r2.cmd http://10.6.7.20/cblr/svc/op/script/system/acme.example.com/?script=win2012r2.cmd
curl -sf -o %SYSTEMROOT%\temp\win2012r2.cmd http://10.6.7.20/cblr/svc/op/script/system/acme.example.com/?script=win2012r2.cmd

if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo Could not download install cmd win2012r2.cmd
    goto err
)

echo Calling %SYSTEMROOT%\temp\win2012r2.cmd
call %SYSTEMROOT%\temp\win2012r2.cmd >%SYSTEMDRIVE%\logs\win2012r2.log 2>&1
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo Postprovisioning failed to run
    exit /b 1
)
goto :eof

:netconf
echo Downloading install script for win_netcfg.cmd
echo curl -sf -o %SYSTEMROOT%\temp\win_netcfg.cmd http://10.6.7.20/cblr/svc/op/script/system/acme.example.com/?script=win_netcfg.cmd
curl -sf -o %SYSTEMROOT%\temp\win_netcfg.cmd http://10.6.7.20/cblr/svc/op/script/system/acme.example.com/?script=win_netcfg.cmd

if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo Could not download netcfg cmd win_netcfg.cmd
    goto err
)

echo Calling %SYSTEMROOT%\temp\win_netcfg.cmd
call %SYSTEMROOT%\temp\win_netcfg.cmd >%SYSTEMDRIVE%\logs\netconf.log 2>&1
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo Networking configuration failed to run
    exit /b 1
)
goto :eof

:err
echo win_installer.cmd failed to run
exit /b 1

:end
exit /b 0
```

And I end up with a c:\logs\installer.log of:

```
Mounting Samba Share WINLOGS to L:
Beginning run stage
Downloading install script for win2012r2.cmd
curl -sf -o C:\Windows\temp\win2012r2.cmd http://10.6.7.20/cblr/svc/op/script/system/acme.example.com/?script=win2012r2.cmd
Calling C:\Windows\temp\win2012r2.cmd
```

And then a c:\logs\win2012r2.log file of:

```
<all the stuff that win2012r2.cmd does>
run stage completed successfully <-- from here to end of the file should be installer.log
Copying setupact.log
Copying setuperr.log
Copying C:\logs\win2012r2.log
Beginning netconf stage
Downloading install script for win_netcfg.cmd
curl -sf -o C:\Windows\temp\win_netcfg.cmd http://10.6.7.20/cblr/svc/op/script/system/acme.example.com/?script=win_netcfg.cmd
Calling C:\Windows\temp\win_netcfg.cmd
```

And then a C:\logs\netconf.log of:

```
< all the stuff netconf does >
netconf stage completed successfully <-- this should be installer.log
```

Comment: you'd have to start a subshell for the other redirects. `call` executes the sub-script as if it was literally embedded in the parent script, so any redirections that occured for the parent will apply to the child as well.

Comment: @MarcB - I'll replace with 'start' instead, but I'm curious as to why the scripts work as expected on Win10, but don't on Win2012.  Also, it's not simply that the child is inheriting the redirection - it's the fact that redirecting the child is also redirecting the parent at the point after the child is called.

Comment: That doesn't seem like it should be happening. I'm on Win 10, where everything works as it should, so I cannot test.

Comment: It might not be an issue, but I would not use the name `start.cmd` since `START` is an internal shell command.

Comment: Yeah I just used that as an example.  Posted the real scripts up, since there may be something else that's causing this.